# Pull out rows matching a binary value in n'th place in a string

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame where I have converted the first column to be binary flags

i.e.:

```
1. 1000 
2. 0010 
3. 0100 
4. 0110 
5. 0010 
6. 1010 
7. 0001 
8. 0011
```

I would like to pull out all rows that match a "1" in the 3rd place.

for example. rows 2, 4, 5, 6 and 8

Unfortunately, there are many rows and the amount changes so I can't just subset the rows.

Comment: Please show your approach. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```
df[grepl("^..1", df$V1),]
#     V1
#1: 0010
#2: 0110
#3: 0010
#4: 1010
#5: 0011
```

The expression `"^..1"` means that you start matching at the beginning of the string (`^`) then you have two digits that can be anything (`..`) and then the third digit must be a 1 (`1`). `grepl` returns a logical index which is true whenever a match is found and false otherwise.

Comment: This worked well. I need to understand how to use grep. Thank you

Comment: I knew regex solution would be prettier, but went with lazy substr solution :)

Comment: @zx8754, I like your solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Substring and compare:

```
myDataFiltered <- myData[ substr(myData$myCol, start = 3, stop = 3) == "1", ]
```

Comment: Simple and easy. Thank you